# git branch on multiple repositories

Tags: git, git-branch

Let's say I have repository `A,B,C`  under directory `Parent`

```
Parent
|-A
|-B
|-C
```

To check current branch of each repository, I have to go under each directory and do `git branch`

Can I do something like `git branch Parent/*`  to list current branch for `A,B and C` in one single command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick bash script to do what you're looking for:

```
for d in */ ; do
    echo "Branches for $d"
    cd $d
    git branch
    echo
    cd ..
done
```

Paste the whole thing in your bash terminal and press enter!